# Autoconf for android. Exists?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I trying to compile "zlib" library for android. sources contains the config file (for GNU autoconf utility). What tool can I use to build the new makefile? (or Android.mk file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you made changes to it, there is no need to compile the zlib library for Android. Android (both SDK and NDK) already has zlib. In your NDK C/C++ code, you can include zlib.h. In your android.mk file, add "-lz" to the LOCAL_LDLIBS line.